# How to use ST_DWithin to query features from one table within a distance of a specific feature or features in another table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, distance, st-dwithin

I'm pretty new with PostGIS. I have a parcel layer and a census block layer in a postgres database, and I would like to be able to query out all census blocks within a specified distance of a specific parcel. I found this example statement, but I'm not sure how to reference the specific parcel in the query, say by parcel ID?

```
SELECT roads.roadname, pois.poiname
FROM roads INNER JOIN pois 
ON ST_DWithin(roads.geog, pois.geog, 1609);`
```

This example uses the `geography` type, but my layers don't have that. They are in *EPSG 3857*; can I use the geometry type and get accurate results?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the coordinate system(s) (SRID) of the tables.  You should also take a stab at attempting a `WHERE` clause, or there is no way we'll be able to help you further (not knowing what the possible attributes are or which attribute value you require).

Comment: I dont think the coordinate system matters if I use ST_DWithin with geog, from what I understand it default to meters, but the layers are in 3857. I just need to understand the proper syntax of how to reference a specific feature, let's say I want to reference a parcel that has an id of 123 in a field called ID. I'm not sure how to apply the where clause at this stage.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would help you to make them sift through comments looking for critical information.  You may have a fundamental flaw in your spatial constraint, since [Web Mercator should not ever be used for ground distance calculations](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/).  Another example [here](http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39404)

Comment: I understand, I did edit the question to include the SRID. Are you saying that even if I use geog if my data is in 3857 there could be issue? I will review the links, thanks for the information.

Comment: [Only one SRID is possible with the geometry type](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) -- 4326 (aka GCS_WGS_1984).  Please **edit** the question to include the fact that you're using a geography type, and to remove the incorrect SRID.

Comment: I see. I edited the question. Though the example shows geog I was planning to use the geometry type and the data is in 3857. I think this is an issue though based on the info you've shared.

Comment: Ack , typo - Only one SRID with **geog**raphy type. **geometry** can have any SRID, but then ST_DWithin  is unreliable if you're not using a geographic or equal-area SRID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using geography type which I am guessing from geog name, query to find all census blocks within 1609 meters ~ 1 mile) of parcel denoted by key '12345'.

```
SELECT census_blocks.*
   FROM census_blocks INNER JOIN parcels 
      ON ST_DWithin(census_blocks.geog, parcels.geog, 1609)
WHERE parcels.parcel_id = '12345';
```

Comment: based on vince's post, I am wondering if I may have an issue with my data being in EPSG 3857. Would it make a difference if I use geography vs geometry?

Comment: I edited my original post, I am not using geography type though that was in the example statement I found.

Comment: You can always figure out the units by looking in spatial_ref_sys:  SELECT proj4text, srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys where srid = 3587;  So looks like that is for Michigan and unit is in meters.  If you are not in Michigan, then that's not the right spatial reference to be using.

Comment: actually the SRID is 3857 which is web mercator. I'm wondering if I need to transform the data before doing this query.